# Stop/Break out from .on("child_added".. if certain condition is met

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase

Alright, so the way I got my set up working goes something like this.

Once new child is added to database `.on("child_added"...` is fired like this:

```
ref.on("child_added", function(snapshot, prevChildKey) {
   ...
}
```

where `ref` is reference to firebase. This child contains time stamp that is compared to local time once certain recurring event happens, something like: `timeFromFirebase < localTime` while this is true I perform certain actions.
I also have a variable named `canPerformAction` initially set to `true` and afterwards set to `false` inside a `child_added`, so I can ignore other signals that are coming in, until I complete actions for current one, here it is

```
var canPerformAction = true;
ref.on("child_added", function(snapshot, prevChildKey) {
   if (!canPerformAction) return;
   canPerformAction = false;
   ...
}
```

Now I need some sort of way to break out/finish `ref.on("child_added"..` if `timeFromFirebase < localTime` becomes false. At the same time when this happens I will set `canPerformAction = true` So I am now taking in new children and whole process begins again.

So in the end something like this:

```
var canPerformAction = true;
   ref.on("child_added", function(snapshot, prevChildKey) {
   if (!canPerformAction) return;

   canPerformAction = false;

   //time is checked repeatedly, I simplified it to if statement here
   if (timeFromFirebase < localTime) {
      ...
   } else {
      canPerformAction = true;
         //Break out here
   }
}
```

Related source: http://firebase.com

Comment: I am not sure if you are copying here what you are actually testing, but the way it's written now, no code after the `return` statement will ever get executed, because it... ahem... returns.

Comment: you have statements after return that will not execute. i think you might want a while loop. while(canPerformAction){ if(timeFromFireBase < localTime) { canPerformAction = false } else{  canPerformAction = true }

Comment: @Aheinlein fixed it to be !canPerformAction

Comment: you are still doing stuff after the return statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do some stuff when a child is added, and continue doing stuff until timeFromFirebase < localTime is false. I think a while loop is what you want.

```
ref.on("child_added", function(snapshot, prevChildKey) {
    while(timeFromFireBase >= localTime){
        //do some stuff
    }
}
```

edit - If you want to use the canPerformAction flag, you can set it up like this, but i dont think that it is necessary to keep the flag if the time is the only thing that changes it

```
canPerformAction = true
ref.on("child_added", function(snapshot, prevChildKey) {
    while(canPerformAction = true){
        if(timeFromFireBase < localTime){
            ...
        }else{
            canPerformAction = false;
        }
    }
}
```